# How to run a script for multiple inputs and save result objects based on the name of input?

Tags: r, time-series

To run the same set of commands and save the result objects for each time series, I wrote the script in the following manner :

```
# Specify time series to be used 

dat <- tsname

# Run a set of commands and fit models with different parameters 
dat.1 <- model1(dat)
dat.2 <- model2(dat)
dat.3 <- model3(dat)

# Save objects for further analysis 

tsname.1 <- dat.1
tsname.2 <- dat.2


save(tsname.1, tsname.2, tsname.3, file = paste0("tsname", ".rda")
```

In this way, we just need to change the script in the beginning and end, save the script for each time series and run each of them individually or in a main script.

The main reason for this method was because I could not find a way to rename the objects created and some search suggested that the above is the only way to do it.

Now as the number of series has increased, it is preferable to either use a for loop, foreach, batch script or commandArgs() to run one script and specify all time series as arguments. 
To make that work though, the script must find a way to assign these objects with name of series itself so that they can be loaded later for further analysis.

How can we make such a script work or is there a better approach ? Which method of looping will work in that case ?

A MWE

```
set.seed(1)
tsdata <- ts(rnorm(250), start = c(1980,1), frequency = 12)
dat <- tsdata
dat.11 <- arima(dat, order = c(1, 1, 1))
dat.21 <- arima(dat, order = c(2, 1, 0))

tsname.11 <- dat.11  # problem is to specify this step in each script
tsname.21 <- dat.21
save(tsname.11, , file = "tsname.rda")
```

*REVISED the code*

How can we execute this script for multiple time series and store the results and result objects for further analysis ? If Batch command can be used, what is the best way to input set of multiple time series?

*How can we run the script for one series, over a set of time series of same or mixed length?*

Comment: Why don't you call the objects `tsname[1:2], dat[1:2]`? Make things easy.

Comment: @smci thats just for example purposes. The names can in general be anything and used numbers as simplest way to distinguish the objects.

Comment: I'm asking why you can't vectorize things? Store them inside one vector of n objects, instead of n separately-named objects which are a pain to access and manage.

Comment: I didnt think that was possible because the names are different for each object, based on the model parameters and would therefore have to be individually assigned. Could you give the code on how to do that?

Comment: Anusha, the [`assign(varname,value...)`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/assign.html) command allows you to assign to whatever variable-name you like. See my code... Note that `assign()` assigns inside whatever the current ['environment'](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/environment.html) (i.e. scope), so if you do an assign inside a function but want it to be created in the toplevel scope, you must pass in that environment.

Comment: When you want to manipulate objects whose names are themselves stored inside a variable, just use `assign()` and its reverse `get()`. And use `ls(pattern=...)` to find object-names, with wildcard matching, to find all matching-named objects in a particular scope:    `ls(pattern='tsname.*')` #[1] "tsname.11" "tsname.21"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I show a couple ways to create and retrieve individual objects using `assign` and `get`, but also provide an alternative where all model runs are stored as different elements of a list. Similarly, I show how you can save each model run in separate files (`soi.1.rda`, etc), but that you can also save *everything* together, in one step :)

```
# ===========================================
# = Set up model params, generate test data =
# ===========================================
mod.param <- 1:5 # orders of AR to try ...
test.soi <- arima.sim(model=list(ar=c(0.5, -0.2)), n=20)

# ===========================================================
# = Create empty vectors/ list to store data and data names =
# ===========================================================
dat.names <- c() # a place to store the names of the individual objects that we'll create
save.names <- c() # the names of the files to save, e.g., "soi.1"
dat.all <- list() # as an altnerative, you can save each analysis in different elements of a list

# ===================================================
# = Loop through each type of model, saving results =
# ===================================================
for(i in 1:length(mod.param)){ # loop through each model you want to run
    temp.dat <- arima(test.soi, order=c(mod.param[i], 0, 0)) # temp.dat is the current model result
    dat.names[i] <- paste("dat", i, sep=".") # dat.names stores the names of all the dat.x objects

    assign(dat.names[i], temp.dat) # use assign() to create an object with name of temp.dat.name

    # dat.all[[dat.names[i]]] <- temp.dat # store the object in a list
    dat.all[[dat.names[i]]] <- get(dat.names[i]) # same as above, but using get(), which complements assign() nicely

    save.name <- paste("soi", i, "rda", sep=".") # I'm assuming the file should be named soi.1.rda, not soi.rda
    save(list=dat.names[i], file=save.name) # save soi.1.rda, soi.2.rda ... etc.
}

# But we don't have to save each file individually!
# We can save a file that contains our list of models (dat.all), as well as each model object (dat.1, dat.2 ... etc.)
all.objs <- ls() # what are all of the object names in our working memory?
dat.objs <- all.objs[all.objs%in%c(dat.names, "dat.all")] # subset to the names of objects we want to save
save(list=dat.objs, file="everything.rda") # save all relevant objects in 1 .rda file


print(dat.1)
print(dat.all$dat.1)
```

## Edit: A different approach that applies each of several models to several time series

Note that the approach might change slightly depending on which models you want to apply to which time series. I've assumed that several models should be applied to each time series, and that the models differ only the the ARIMA order.

The results can be saved as 1 nested list (different model results grouped *under* different time series), or with model results for each time series being saved as a separate file.

```
# ============================================================
# = Generate many time series, many sets of model parameters =
# ============================================================
# Model parameters
n.Params <- 5
ar.orders <- 1:n.Params # orders of AR to try ...
i.orders <- rep(0, n.Params)
ma.orders <- rep(0,n.Params)
arima.params <- as.list(as.data.frame(rbind(ar.orders, i.orders, ma.orders)))

# Time Series Data
n.ts <- 10 # number of time series
test.soi <- quote(as.numeric(arima.sim(model=list(ar=c(0.2, 0.4)), n=sample(20:30, 1))))
all.soi.ts <- replicate(n.ts, eval(test.soi))
names(all.soi.ts) <- paste("soi", 1:n.ts, sep=".")

# ==============================================
# = Function to be applied to each time series =
# ==============================================
# Analyze time series
ats <- function(TS, arimaParams){
    dat.all <- list() # as an altnerative, you can save each analysis in different elements of a list
    for(i in 1:length(arimaParams)){ # loop through each model you want to run
        temp.dat <- arima(TS, order=arimaParams[[i]]) # temp.dat is the current model result
        dat.all[[i]] <- temp.dat # store the object in a list
    }
    dat.all 
}

# =========================
# = All Results in 1 List =
# =========================
AllResults <- lapply(all.soi.ts, ats, arima.params) # multilevel list – top level is each TS, within each TS group are the results of all models applied to that time series
save(AllResults, file="everything.rda") # save this big list as 1 file

# ========================================================================
# = Each time series gets its own file and its own list of model results =
# ========================================================================
for(i in 1:length(all.soi.ts)){ # if you want many files, 1 file per time series, use this for loop
    temp.ts <- all.soi.ts[[i]]
    soi.name <- paste("soi", i, sep=".")
    assign(soi.name, ats(temp.ts, arima.params))
    save(list=soi.name, file=paste(soi.name, "rda", sep=".")) # each file will have a name like "soi.1.rda", containing the results of all models applied to the first time series
}
```

Comment: Thankyou. This is helpful for analysis of one time series. How can we scale it for multiple time series. If we put this in a function, can we loop it over a set of other time series using apply functions or batch script?

Comment: @Anusha How are the other time series stored? Are they the same length and stored in a matrix, or different lengths and stored in a list, or are they just separate objects? If separate objects, what are the names of those objects?

Comment: The time series are of same length and didnt combine them in an object as till now, was loading each series separately as was running each script individually. Can store them in a matrix or list.

Comment: Time series are stored in csv format and can combine them in a list or matrix. Names will be that of time series.

Comment: @Anusha I've updated my answer – I assume time series are stored in a list (do `print(all.soi.ts)` to see example), and that you are simply using `arima()` to analyze each time series, with each model's parameters being stored in a row of a matrix (see `arima.params` for example, but note that you can put it whatever AR, MA, or I orders you want). Also, although I'm calling these "params", they are really the orders of the arima() model. I assume that you want to analyze each time series with each model.

Answer (score 1):

The function sets `datname` to the name of the input variable.  Then define a list `L` of model outputs and add names.  Finally use `with(L, ...)` to regard the list component names as variable names in ... and use `save(list = ..., ...)` which allows specification of the variables as a character string of names.  Now we only have to set up the data and call the function to run it.  If you have several data sets call the function for each one.

```
run <- function(dat, datname = deparse(subset(dat))) {

  L <- list(
       arima(dat, order = c(1, 1, 1)),
       arima(dat, order = c(2, 1, 0))
     )
  names(L) <- paste(datname, seq_along(L), sep = ".")

  with(L, save(list = names(L), file = paste0(datname, ".rda")))

}

set.seed(1)
soi <- ts(rnorm(250), start = c(1980,1), frequency = 12)
run(soi)
```

Another possibility might be to save the entire list rather than its components separately. That is, replace the `with` statement with

```
  listname <- paste0(datname, ".models")
  assign(listname, L)
  save(list = listname, file = paste0(datname, ".rda"))
```

**REVISED** Some corrections and added alternative at end.

Comment: Thankyou for efficient code. What will be the best way to apply this function over a set of time series? *lapply or batch script?

Comment: If you just have a few then this would be sufficient: `fun(soi); fun(soi2); fun(soi3)` or if you have a character vector of their names, `nms`, then `for(nm in nms) fun(get(nm), nm)` .

Comment: Isnt datname to be deparse(substitute(dat)) or quote(dat) ?

Answer (score 1):

When you want to manipulate objects whose names are themselves stored inside a variable, just use `assign()` and its reverse `get()`. And use `ls()` to see which objects exist in a particular scope.

The objects don't need to be stored separately as `tsname.1/2/3, model1/2/3`??
You can make it real simple if you just store a vector `dat[1:3]`.
Indeed you can have a vector of `model[1:3]` too. Use vectorization. It's your friend.

Use the `assign("tsname.21", object,...)` command and its reverse get("tsname.21") to manipulate objects by string name. Just be consistent about whether you prefer to refer to objnames or objects.

```
set.seed(1)
tsdata <- ts(rnorm(250), start = c(1980,1), frequency = 12)
dat <- tsdata

set.seed(1)
tsdata <- ts(rnorm(250), start = c(1980,1), frequency = 12)
dat <- tsdata

create_model <- function(data, params, objname.prefix='tsname.', envir=.GlobalEnv) {
  objname = paste(objname.prefix, params[1], params[2], sep='') # both assigns and prints it
  the.model <- arima(dat, order = params)
  assign(objname, the.model, envir) # create the var in the global env

  # If you want, you can return the varname 
  return(objname)
}

# dat.11 <- arima(dat, order = c(1, 1, 1))
create_model(dat, c(1, 1, 1))

# dat.21 <- arima(dat, order = c(2, 1, 0))
create_model(dat, c(2, 1, 0))

#tsname.11 <- dat.11  # problem is to specify this step in each script
#tsname.21 <- dat.21
save(tsname.11, , file = "tsname.rda")

# Use `ls(pattern=...)` to find object-names, with wildcard matching.
all.models <- ls(pattern='tsname.*')
#[1] "tsname.11" "tsname.21"

#############
# Refactor your original code similarly.
dat <- tsname

# Run a set of commands and fit models with different parameters 
dat[1] <- model1(dat)
dat[2] <- model2(dat)
dat[3] <- model3(dat)
# or maybe figure out how to use sapply here

# Save objects for further analysis 
tsname <- dat[1:2] # instead of tsname.1 <- dat.1, tsname.2 <- dat.2

#
save(tsname, file = paste0("tsname", ".rda")
```

Comment: Thank you. In my actual code, I had used model parameters like 23, 49, 58  etc to help me check the specification used in the model and not 1, 2, 3. Can this example be extended to cover this case ?

Comment: Why not just create tsname.11, tsname.21 directly (in `create_model()`) like above, save and load them directly etc etc.? I really don't get why you need to create temporary copies dat.11, dat.21. This only introduces dangers with consistency etc.

Comment: And use the command `get("tsname.21")` (which is the reverse of `assign`) to get the object associated with that name. Just be consistent about whether you prefer to refer to objnames or objects.